# Как сделать изображение на все окно PyQt?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyside2, qss

Есть окно, составленное с помощью *Qt Designer* и переведенное в модуль **`.py`**. 
Я сделал, чтобы кнопки и все остальное растягивалось вместе с окном, но, т.к. используется `QGridLayout`, я не могу воткнуть `QLabel`, который бы являлся фоном с картинкой.

Интернет прошерстил, находил варианты, но там фон появлялся и на кнопках и на `LineEdit`.

Как мне можно сделать фон окна, в таком случае? 
Пожалуйста, направьте, в каком направлении искать решение. Возможно я плохо гуглил.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_seeTable(object):
    def setupUi(self, seeTable):
        seeTable.setObjectName("seeTable")
        seeTable.resize(931, 720)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(seeTable.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        seeTable.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        seeTable.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(930, 720))
        seeTable.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        seeTable.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(seeTable)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 79))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 67))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe Print")
        font.setPointSize(39)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.returnToMain = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.returnToMain.setEnabled(True)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Algerian")
        font.setPointSize(23)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.returnToMain.setFont(font)
        self.returnToMain.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.returnToMain.setObjectName("returnToMain")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.returnToMain)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.label_12.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_12.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.label_13.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.label_13.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.label_13.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_13.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_13.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgba(0, 125, 215, 0);")
        self.label_13.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_13.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_13)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(895, 400))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.tableWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setLineWidth(1)
        self.tableWidget.setAutoScrollMargin(22)
        self.tableWidget.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.tableWidget.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.viewProducts = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.viewProducts.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(155, 33))
        self.viewProducts.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Malgun Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.viewProducts.setFont(font)
        self.viewProducts.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.viewProducts.setObjectName("viewProducts")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.viewProducts)
        self.viewOrders = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.viewOrders.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 33))
        self.viewOrders.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Malgun Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.viewOrders.setFont(font)
        self.viewOrders.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.viewOrders.setObjectName("viewOrders")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.viewOrders)
        self.viewDelivering = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.viewDelivering.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 33))
        self.viewDelivering.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Malgun Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.viewDelivering.setFont(font)
        self.viewDelivering.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.viewDelivering.setObjectName("viewDelivering")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.viewDelivering)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_11.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 20))
        self.label_11.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.label_11.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.label_11.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.label_11.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(37, 37))
        self.lineEdit_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(37, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lineEdit_6.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.deleteButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.deleteButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 37))
        self.deleteButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.deleteButton.setFont(font)
        self.deleteButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.deleteButton.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.deleteButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.deleteButton.setObjectName("deleteButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.deleteButton)
        self.infoButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.infoButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.infoButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(35, 37))
        self.infoButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(35, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.infoButton.setFont(font)
        self.infoButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.infoButton.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.infoButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.infoButton.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(255, 99, 47);\n"
"")
        self.infoButton.setObjectName("infoButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.infoButton)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.viewExcel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.viewExcel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 37))
        self.viewExcel.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 33))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Malgun Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.viewExcel.setFont(font)
        self.viewExcel.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.viewExcel.setObjectName("viewExcel")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.viewExcel)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        seeTable.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(seeTable)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(seeTable)

    def retranslateUi(self, seeTable):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        seeTable.setWindowTitle(_translate("seeTable", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" color:#ffea00;\">Осьминог</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.returnToMain.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<---"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic;\">Прибыль за все время:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.viewProducts.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Товар в наличии"))
        self.viewOrders.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Заказы"))
        self.viewDelivering.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Поставки"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic;\">Удаление</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.deleteButton.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Удалить"))
        self.infoButton.setText(_translate("seeTable", "?"))
        self.viewExcel.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Открыть таблицу в EXCEL"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    seeTable = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_seeTable()
    ui.setupUi(seeTable)
    seeTable.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пример проблемы на картинке:

[image: Окно]

Answer (score 0):

Я закомментировал некоторые строки для тестирования.

`StyleSheet` вам в помощь:

```
   ...
    self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("""
        #centralwidget {
            border-image: url(panda.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
        }
    """)
    ...
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_seeTable(object):
    def setupUi(self, seeTable):
        seeTable.setObjectName("seeTable")
        seeTable.resize(931, 720)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(seeTable.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        seeTable.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
#        seeTable.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(930, 720))
        seeTable.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        seeTable.setStyleSheet("")
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(seeTable)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 79))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 67))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe Print")
        font.setPointSize(39)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.returnToMain = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.returnToMain.setEnabled(True)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Algerian")
        font.setPointSize(23)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.returnToMain.setFont(font)
        self.returnToMain.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.returnToMain.setObjectName("returnToMain")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.returnToMain)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.label_12.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_12.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.label_13.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.label_13.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.label_13.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_13.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_13.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgba(0, 125, 215, 0);")
        self.label_13.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_13.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_13)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        
#        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(895, 400))
#        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.tableWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setLineWidth(1)
        self.tableWidget.setAutoScrollMargin(22)
        self.tableWidget.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.tableWidget.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        
# +
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(9)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(12)
        
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.viewProducts = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.viewProducts.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(155, 33))
        self.viewProducts.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Malgun Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.viewProducts.setFont(font)
        self.viewProducts.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.viewProducts.setObjectName("viewProducts")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.viewProducts)
        self.viewOrders = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.viewOrders.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 33))
        self.viewOrders.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Malgun Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.viewOrders.setFont(font)
        self.viewOrders.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.viewOrders.setObjectName("viewOrders")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.viewOrders)
        self.viewDelivering = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.viewDelivering.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 33))
        self.viewDelivering.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Malgun Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.viewDelivering.setFont(font)
        self.viewDelivering.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.viewDelivering.setObjectName("viewDelivering")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.viewDelivering)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_11.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 20))
        self.label_11.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.label_11.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.label_11.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.label_11.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(37, 37))
        self.lineEdit_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(37, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lineEdit_6.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.deleteButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.deleteButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 37))
        self.deleteButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.deleteButton.setFont(font)
        self.deleteButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.deleteButton.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.deleteButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.deleteButton.setObjectName("deleteButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.deleteButton)
        self.infoButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.infoButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.infoButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(35, 37))
        self.infoButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(35, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.infoButton.setFont(font)
        self.infoButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.infoButton.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.infoButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.infoButton.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(255, 99, 47);\n"
"")
        self.infoButton.setObjectName("infoButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.infoButton)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.viewExcel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.viewExcel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 37))
        self.viewExcel.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 33))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Malgun Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.viewExcel.setFont(font)
        self.viewExcel.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.viewExcel.setObjectName("viewExcel")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.viewExcel)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        seeTable.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(seeTable)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(seeTable)

    def retranslateUi(self, seeTable):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        seeTable.setWindowTitle(_translate("seeTable", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" color:#ffea00;\">Панда</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.returnToMain.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<---"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic;\">Прибыль за все время:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.viewProducts.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Товар в наличии"))
        self.viewOrders.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Заказы"))
        self.viewDelivering.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Поставки"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("seeTable", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic;\">Удаление</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.deleteButton.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Удалить"))
        self.infoButton.setText(_translate("seeTable", "?"))
        self.viewExcel.setText(_translate("seeTable", "Открыть таблицу в EXCEL"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_seeTable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("""
            #centralwidget {
                border-image: url(panda.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
            }
        """)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**panda.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @МихаилПетухов что не так?